Question on proof of Proposition A. 5 in the appdendix of Shafarevich's book: Basic Algebraic Geometry 1
The Proposition in question is as follows:
Let $L$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $K$, and $G$ a finite group of quasilinear maps of $L$. Assume that every element $e \neq \phi \in G$ has associated automorphism $g \neq id_K$. Then $L$ has a basis consisting of elements invariant under $G$.
The proof in book stated that "By assumption the different maps in $G$ have different associated homomorphisms", and this is where I am having trouble with. I wonder if any one can explain this to me?
A quasilinear map on L is a map $\phi : L \to L$ such that $\phi(x + y) = \phi(x)+\phi(y)$ , and there exists a field automorphism $g \in Aut(K)$ such that $\phi(\alpha x)=g(\alpha)\phi(x)$ for all $x,y\in L, \alpha \in K $.
The following is my construction of some nontrivial examples of quasilinear maps:
Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}, a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $L=K(\sqrt{3})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}+(c+d\sqrt{2})\sqrt{3}= \{a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}, a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, then $L$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $K$.
Define $g \in Aut(K)$ by $g(a+b\sqrt{2})=a-b\sqrt{2}$, and define $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2 $ by $\phi_1(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})=2a-2b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}-d\sqrt{6}$ and $\phi_2(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})=3a-3b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}-d\sqrt{6}$ respectively.
To construct such a quasilinear map,  I started with the requirements $\phi_1(1)=2$, $\phi_1(\sqrt{2})=\phi_1(\sqrt{2}\cdot 1)=g(\sqrt{2})\phi_1(1)=-2\sqrt{2}$ and $\phi_1(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}$, then we can get $\phi_1(\sqrt{6})=\phi_1(\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{3})=g(\sqrt{2})\phi_1(\sqrt{3})=-\sqrt{6}$, so the formula of $\phi_1$ can be obtained as above. $\phi_2$ is similar except that $\phi_2(1)=3$.
Note that the composition $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})=6a+6b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$. And $\phi_1$ has an inverse by requiring $\phi_1^{-1}(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. The discussion for $\phi_2$ is similar. However, the examples lead to an infinite group G, not
as in the Proposition A.5 of book.
Post comment:
The problem is solved below by lysikov. Meanwhile, i found my construction of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ actually implies that the associated $g$ to $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1 \neq e$ is indeed $id_K$, contradicting to the assumption of the proposition.


Typo check - should the second sentence of the proposition have the assumption $g\neq id_L$ instead of $g\neq id_K$? 2. Probably not super important, but could you remind me what a quasilinear map is?


As I checked just now, there should be no typos.

Maybe this can be better clarified by giving the exact definition of a quasilinear map on L: a map $\phi : L \to L$ such that $\phi(x + y) = \phi(x)+\phi(y)$ , and there exists a field automorphism $g \in Aut(K)$ such that $\phi(\alpha x)=g(\alpha)\phi(x)$ for all $x,y\in L, \alpha \in K $. I shall add this to the original post with  nontrivial example(s) of quasilinear maps .

It is not hard to see that the map $A \colon G \to \operatorname{Aut}(K)$ sending $\phi \in G$ to the corresponding automorphism $g \in \operatorname{Aut}(K)$ is a group homomorphism, that is, if $\phi(\alpha x) = g(\alpha) \phi(x)$ and $\psi(\alpha x) = h(\alpha) \psi(x)$, then $(\psi \circ \phi)(\alpha x) = (h \circ g)(\alpha) \cdot (\psi \circ \phi)(x)$.
The condition of the theorem says that the kernel of this homomorhism is trivial, so the homomorphism is injective (different maps in G have different associated homomorphisms).

I see. Thank you.
